# Создать цветовую шкалу в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

есть матрица с числовыми данными (Index_Sver_total), нужно сформировать цветовую шкалу, на которой каждому цвету сопоставлен определенный диапазон значений. Конкретно: зеленому соответствует диапазон 1-300, синему 301-1000, желтому 1001-4000, красному 4001-10000, коричневому > 10001. То есть должно быть аналогично как здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
nllcrnrlat=53.871
nurcrnrlat=61.869
nllcrnrlon=72.9
nurcrnrlon=90
clevs = [0,300,1000,4000,10000]
ax = plt.subplot
ax = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=nllcrnrlat,urcrnrlat=nurcrnrlat,llcrnrlon=nllcrnrlon,urcrnrlon=nurcrnrlon,resolution='h')
ax.drawparallels(np.arange(nllcrnrlat,nurcrnrlat,0.186),labels=[True,False,False,False])
ax.drawmeridians(np.arange(nllcrnrlon,nurcrnrlon,0.225),labels=[False,False,False,True])
cs = ax.contourf(lons,lats,Index_Sver_total,clevs)
ax.colorbar(cs)
plt.title('Index Sverlova')
plt.show()
```

Только нужно сделать с помощью imshow (без интерполяции). На данный момент получилось вот так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
nllcrnrlat=53.871
nurcrnrlat=61.869
nllcrnrlon=72.9
nurcrnrlon=90
clevs = [0,300,1000,4000,10000]
ax = plt.subplot
ax = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=nllcrnrlat,urcrnrlat=nurcrnrlat,llcrnrlon=nllcrnrlon,urcrnrlon=nurcrnrlon,resolution='h')
ax.drawparallels(np.arange(nllcrnrlat,nurcrnrlat,0.186),labels=[True,False,False,False])
ax.drawmeridians(np.arange(nllcrnrlon,nurcrnrlon,0.225),labels=[False,False,False,True])
img = ax.imshow(Index_Sver_total,interpolation='none',cmap='jet')
ax.colorbar(img)
plt.title('Index Sverlova')
plt.show()
```

Но это есть не то, что нужно, потому что значения в матрице меняются на каждой итерации, и ,соответственно, при каждом выводе изображения значения в шкале будут "прыгать", но шкала должна быть неизменной. Нужно построить шкалу, аналогичную 1 картинке. Почитал документацию библиотеки matplotlib про imshow и colorbar, но безуспешно. Буду благодарен вашей помощи.

Comment: Я три раза прочитал объяснение, почему это "не то, что нужно", но так и не понял.

Comment: Что вам не понятно в объяснении? Мне нужно построить шкалу аналогичную той, что в 1 изображении, но используя imshow, потому что в 1 изображении присутствует интерполяция (а мне она  не нужна).

Comment: Чтобы зафиксировать шкалу выполните `plt.clim(low, upper)`.

Comment: А как  каждому цвету свой диапазон задать как на 1 картинке, только с помощью imshow?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, что цветовую шкалу можно построить,задав в imshow параметр  cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['g', 'b', 'y', 'r', 'maroon']).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Но еще не разобрался, как  задать для кажого цвета числовой диапазон ('g': 1-300, 'b': 301-1000,'y': 1001-4000,'r': 4001-10000,'maroon': 10001-бесконечность). plt.clim(low, upper) - задает только границы шкалы, так что это несовсем то, что нужно.